# How can I use the same instance of UserManager across projects?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, identityserver4

So I have an Asp.Net Core Mvc IdentityServer web project, another web project for managing IdentityServer(Admin), and an IdentityServer web api project.

They're all in the same visual studio solution.

Both the IdentityServer and Api projects have their own Startup.cs classes where I am registering Identity like this

```
services.AddIdentity<EntityUser, EntityRole>()
            .AddRoles<EntityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityServerDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

The Admin project registers the HttpClient in its Program.cs for communicating with web api

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("IdentityServerApi",
           client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_BASEADDRESS))
          .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
          {
              var handler = sp.GetService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
                  .ConfigureHandler(
                      authorizedUrls: new[] { ApplicationConsts.ApiBaseUrl },
                      scopes: new[] { ApplicationConsts.ApiName });
              return handler;
          });

        builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
            .CreateClient("IdentityServerApi"));
```

What I'm trying to do is force a user to reset his password on login.
So to achieve that, in IdentityServer project's Account/Login controller action, I generate a token and redirect the user to a password reset page in the Admin project:

```
if (isForcePasswordResetRequired)
            {                  
                if (hasUserDoneForcePasswordReset)
                {
                    return await SignInTheUser(model, user, context);
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, false);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        // show him password reset form 
                        var token =  await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
                        token = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token);
                        var callbackUrl = ApplicationConsts.AdminBaseUrl + $"/Account/ResetPassword?userId={user.Id}&token={token}";
                       
                        return Redirect(callbackUrl);
                       
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return await SignInTheUser(model, user, context);
            }
```

Once the user is redirected to the Password reset page (which is in the Admin project), he is asked to enter new password and confirm new password. On submit the below function is called to forward the  information to the Api layer:

```
public async Task SavePassword()
{
    ResetPasswordDto resetPasswordDto = new ResetPasswordDto();
    resetPasswordDto.UserId = userId_par;
    resetPasswordDto.Token = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token_par);
    resetPasswordDto.Password = userPasswordDto.Password;

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;
    var url = $"{ApplicationConsts.ApiBaseDnsUrl}/Account/user/resetpassword";
    httpResponse = await HttpClientService.AnonymousHttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<ResetPasswordDto>(url, resetPasswordDto);

    if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        toastService.ShowSuccess("Password changed successfully. Please log in using your new password.");
        NavManager.NavigateTo("AdminBaseUrl");
    }
    else
    {
        toastService.ShowError("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

from there an Api action is called, which calls a repository method to do the password reset as below:

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> UserResetPassword(string userId, string token, string newPassword)
    {   
        token = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token);
        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        var res = await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword);
        if (res.Succeeded)
        {
            return res;
        }
        else throw new Exception(string.Join(",", res.Errors.Select(x=> x.Code)));
    }
```

The issue I'm running into is that the token is not getting validated even though the token that was generated in IdentityServer is identical to that which is being passed above into the ResetPasswordAsync method. Security stamp is not null.

My guess is it has to do something with the fact that the token was generated in the IdentityServer project which uses its own instance of UserManager and then I'm trying to validate it thru the Api project which again has its own instance of the UserManager.

If that is true, how can I use the instance of the UserManager across different projects, in this case IdentityServer and Api projects?

Comment: No, you can't do that like that, and you shouldn't do that like that. You should protect your API end points with Jwt token authentication; that is, you should pass the Jwt token, issued by the IdentityServer, in the HTTP calls to the end points. This procedure may be transparent and automatic depending on the VS project template you chose. Otherwise, you'll need to add the jwt token manually to the Authorization header of your HttpClient service.

Comment: Before you go on with your project using IdentityServer make sure you've read 
this article ( https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-6-and-authentication-servers/#comments ) by Microsoft , 
and its accompanied comments. Personally, I'm done with IdentityServer.